# Keeping state of an angular app after using browser's back button

Tags: javascript, angularjs, session-storage

I made an angular app that makes the user able to search through an assortment of products. This application will run on a Drupal page. This all works fine.

When I click a product my intention is to open another static drupal page with a product detail directive in it. The product detail page will have the product id or alias in the url. If the product detail page opens the directive will load the product detail by the id in the URL.

Now when I user the browser's back button, the search results will be gone and the assortment browser will be in pristine state.

How can I keep the state? Is it wise to use sessionStorage?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$rootScope(SPA applications)` to maintain the state or you can use `sessionStorage`